# What is data:image/gif appended to my url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Asp.net MVC 4 application and examining the log files I can see several errors about potentially dangerous requests with ":" character. I have found that the urls where this errors are happening are called like this:

```
/Products/306/data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP/yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7
```

What is this "data:image" stuff? I did Googled around and found that this notation can be used to render an inline image. But who is appending this to the URL? How do I prevent this from causing exceptions in my application?

Comment: That sounds like a buggy browser thinking it's a relative path.  What `User-Agent`?

Comment: If you use editor plugin like TinyMCE, there are chances that images are pasted in the editor and posted to controller.

Comment: Yeah you will get this sort of thing in CMS's

Comment: It is an e-commerce site, no CMS and no TinyMCE stuff. Also the correct url is http://www.domain.com.br/Products/306 . Something is adding that data:image stuff in the client browser.
User agent is Chrome!

Comment: I've found that when this data:image is appended the URL, the user agent is actually "GbPlugin", then I found that this is a software installed by some internet banking in Brazil. This program is supposed to "protect" the user from phishing and other stuff.
I'm thinking in use IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite module to rewrite the URL without the data:image but first I'll have to learn how to use this module, if any one can help me writing the rule, I appreciate. I need to be able to get this http://www.domain.com.br/Products/123/data:image/blablabla and rewrite it to http://www.domain.com.br/Products/123.